# How to encode a string into windows-1251 charset?

Tags: dart

How can I encode a string into windows-1251 charset?
I'm going to post a form data into a backend, which internaly uses windows-1251, so I need to encode a string properly so that the message will be readable in the backend.

Here's how I send it

```
final codec = const Windows1251Codec(allowInvalid: false);
final encoded = codec.encode(message);
print('${codec.name}: encode "$message" to "$encoded"');

Response r = await Requests.post('http://abackend.com/page.php?action=send', 
   body: {'body': encoded},
   bodyEncoding: RequestBodyEncoding.FormURLEncoded
);
```

console:

> I/flutter ( 7423): windows-1251: encode "привет" to "[239, 240, 232,
> 226, 229, 242]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package that can do this called [`enough_convert`](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_convert).

Usage example:

```dart
import 'package:enough_convert/enough_convert.dart';

void main() {
  final codec = const Windows1251Codec(allowInvalid: false);
  final input = 'To encode input';
  final encoded = codec.encode(input);
}
```

Comment: I suppose it's correct, but should I use some additional canversions before sending `encoded ` in post form? When I send the `encoded` to the backend, it see it like `[229, 239, 251, 32, 252, 228, 249, 237]`

Comment: @rozerro Share how you're sending the data. That list of ints is your encoded string, you're probably just not sending it correctly.

Comment: thus in the backend it looks like `[239, 240, 232, 226, 229, 242]`

Comment: @rozerro You can't reencode your data as your networking package is doing. You're encoding with windows1251, then reencoding with whatever that package is using. I would very highly discourage using that package.

Comment: ...do you mean `Requests` package? If I disable the line with `bodyEncoding` then it doen't change the situation. So the way I sending it in general is true?

Comment: @rozerro Simply removing the bodyEncoding does not stop it from encoding. There is a default value. This is a limitation of the package. Use the http package or equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229943/discussion-between-rozerro-and-christopher-moore).